# Jupyter Notebook: HTML rendered in one cell messes up HTML rendered in another

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook

I'm building a report in a Jupyter notebook.  Aside from the data visualizations, I have some nicely formatted documentation from a Google doc, with various text colors and formatting, footnotes etc.  I want to include portions of the documentation sporadically throughout the notebook, and so have split the Google doc into segments that I want to render in specific notebook cells, downloaded each portion as HTML, and am now trying to include it in the notebook with

`IPython.display.HTML(""" [html string] """)`

The first time I try to render HTML like this, it looks fine.  However, as soon as I try to render a second piece of HTML in a separate cell, **not only does it not render properly with tons of random whitespace and obscured text, it also messes up the initial cell of rendered HTML that previously looked fine.**  Why is the output of one cell altering the output of another?  And what can I do to mitigate this issue?

```
#setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
from bokeh.charts.operations import blend
from bokeh.charts import Bar, Donut, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.charts.attributes import CatAttr
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import folium
output_notebook()
import IPython as ipython
import IPython.core.display as di

# This line will hide code by default when the notebook is exported as HTML
di.display_html('<script>jQuery(function() {if (jQuery("body.notebook_app").length == 0) { jQuery(".input_area").toggle(); jQuery(".prompt").toggle();}});</script>', raw=True)

ipython.display.HTML("""<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><style type="text/css">ol{margin:0;padding:0}table td,table th{padding:0}.c8{background-color:#ffffff;max-width:468pt;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt}.c4{font-size:12pt;color:#cc0000;font-weight:700}.c6{orphans:2;widows:2;height:11pt}.c5{line-height:1.0;orphans:2;widows:2}.c10{orphans:2;widows:2}.c0{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}.c9{color:#1155cc;text-decoration:underline}.c1{color:#4c515a;font-size:12pt}.c3{width:33%;height:1px}.c7{font-weight:700}.c2{font-size:10pt}.title{padding-top:0pt;color:#000000;font-size:26pt;padding-bottom:3pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}.subtitle{padding-top:0pt;color:#666666;font-size:15pt;padding-bottom:16pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}p{margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}h1{padding-top:20pt;color:#000000;font-size:20pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h2{padding-top:18pt;color:#000000;font-size:16pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h3{padding-top:16pt;color:#434343;font-size:14pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h4{padding-top:14pt;color:#666666;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h5{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h6{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;font-style:italic;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}</style></head><body class="c8"><p class="c10"><span class="c4">SEX AND AGE DISAGGREGATION</span><sup class="c4"><a href="#ftnt1" id="ftnt_ref1">[1]</a></sup></p><p class="c10"><span class="c1">Across the response, the largest age </span><span class="c1">brackets</span><span class="c1">&nbsp;were, understandably </span><span class="c1 c7">18-59 </span><span class="c1">and </span><span class="c1 c7">5-17</span><sup class="c1 c7"><a href="#ftnt2" id="ftnt_ref2">[2]</a></sup><span class="c1">&nbsp;- not surprising, as these are also the widest age </span><span class="c1">brackets</span><span class="c1">. </span></p><p class="c6"><span></span></p><hr class="c3"><div><p class="c5"><a href="#ftnt_ref1" id="ftnt1">[1]</a><span class="c2">&nbsp;</span><span class="c2">Further breakdown of SADD and </span><span class="c2">country of origin</span><span class="c2">&nbsp;data by district/camp within Turkey, Greece or the Balkans is also available. </span><span class="c1">&nbsp;</span></p></div><div><p class="c5"><a href="#ftnt_ref2" id="ftnt2">[2]</a><span class="c2">&nbsp;The range of the current age brackets being used (i.e. the 18-59 brackets) significantly reduces the usefulness of age in analyzing disaggregated data. Greater insights could be gathered around the age-based needs of populations served by Mercy Corps if age were collected using</span><span class="c2">&nbsp;</span><span class="c2 c9"><a class="c0" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://thedig.mercycorps.org/page/21&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1471779169512000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGe-EGnyFOFGO8Kg7MJ0ibxA6YYzw">Mercy Corps&rsquo; recommended age brackets</a></span><span class="c2">, or preferably, collecting the exact age of household members as well as that of registered individuals. </span></p></div></body></html>""")


ipython.display.HTML("""<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><style type="text/css">ol{margin:0;padding:0}table td,table th{padding:0}.c1{background-color:#ffffff;max-width:468pt;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt}.c2{orphans:2;widows:2}.c0{color:#4c515a;font-size:12pt}.title{padding-top:0pt;color:#000000;font-size:26pt;padding-bottom:3pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}.subtitle{padding-top:0pt;color:#666666;font-size:15pt;padding-bottom:16pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}p{margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}h1{padding-top:20pt;color:#000000;font-size:20pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h2{padding-top:18pt;color:#000000;font-size:16pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h3{padding-top:16pt;color:#434343;font-size:14pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h4{padding-top:14pt;color:#666666;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h5{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h6{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;font-style:italic;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}</style></head><body class="c1"><p class="c2"><span class="c0">The beneficiary population in Izmir, Turkey is a relatively even split between female/male, with a slightly higher female </span><span class="c0">population</span><span class="c0">. </span></p></body></html>""")
```

After running each of the `ipython.display.HTML` commands above, if I then clear the output of the second cell, the output of the first returns to perfect formatting.

Comment: you are inserting two times styles for the same target, so the last remains. Also you are inserting two times elemtens that should be only once, like `<html> <head> <body>` I don't know if `ipython.display.HTML` take care of this, if not, is up to the browser, how to handle that bad document. May be that they are iframes?

Comment: It sounds like iframes are what I need.  Any tips on how to make that work?  I tried replacing the calls to `ipython.display.HTML` with calls to `ipython.display.IFrame` but the output is now showing a 404 error.

Comment: Was able to make this work properly by serving the HTML files off of Dropbox as described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/764641/how-to-serve-html-off-my-dropbox/931469#931469).  However, another odd issue has cropped up - now that I'm including the IFrames in the notebook, the script I've been using to hide the code cells and just show output when downloaded as HTML no longer seems to work.

Comment: Solved again - just had to make sure the script to hide code was at the bottom of the notebook and ran after all the IFrames loaded.  Thanks so much for the idea!

Comment: Please write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was caused by multiple calls to `IPython.display.HTML` on the full HTML string created from a Google doc download, with styling in one string conflicting with the styling in others.

Solution is to use IFrames, replacing calls to `IPython.display.HTML` with calls to `IPython.display.IFrame`.  Additionally, rather than simply including the HTML string downloaded from Google docs, the HTML document must be hosted on a web server to render properly in the notebook.  [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/764641/how-to-serve-html-off-my-dropbox/931469#931469) provides a nice solution using dropbox to serve up the files.